# `photos` permission of facebook graph-api is hindering the login process

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Whenever I tried to add `photos` permission on my scope it always giving this message while login:

[image]

Without `photos` permission it is working perfectly. Here is my code:

```
document.getElementById('fb-login-btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
   FB.login((response) => {
     statusChangeCallback(response);
   }, {scope: 'public_profile,photos', return_scopes: true}); //{scope: 'public_profile,email', return_scopes: true});
 }, false);
```

I don't think the problem lies in code, because the same problem also occurred with default `facebook login button` as well, when I added `photos` permission. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no permission called `photos`.

**`user_photos`** is what it is actually named.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference/user_photos

Comment: Thanks for your comment. With `user_photos` as a permission on my scope I am getting this message after login `Invalid Scopes: user_photos. This message is only shown to developers. Users of your app will ignore these permissions if present. Please read the documentation for valid permissions at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions`

Comment: Your app is probably in live mode already? You can not ask for un-approved permissions in live mode, you need to submit your app’s use of that permission for review first.

Comment: Yes I am working with a live firebase hosting. Because facebook won't allow me to put `http://localhost` as app's url cause they only allow `https://` not `http://`. But my app hasn't finished yet, so how could I ask them for permission? I mean with what details?

Comment: You need to finish implementing the functionality first, before you can submit for review, and that means you must work in dev mode. You can use a service like ngrok.com to get an HTTPS tunnel to your localhost.

Comment: Thanks man. It means a lot. I am looking into it. Stay safe stay blessed. :)

Comment: Brother after setting up `ngrok url`, facebook still getting the same message for `user_photos` permission which is `Invalid Scopes: user_photos. This message is only shown to developers. Users of your app will ignore these permissions if present. Please read the documentation for valid permissions at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions` :(
My ngrok url: `https://79e41c90c462.ngrok.io/UploadToFB/`

Comment: As the app developer (/any user with a role in the app), you should be able to simply ignore this message, and still grant the permission.

Comment: After pressing `Ok` button at the bottom of the `error` pop up view, in `function statusChangeCallback(response)` I am getting `response.status === 'connected'` false. Hence unable to authenticate if I ignore it.

Comment: Is your app in dev mode now?

Comment: I just change the `App URL` on `developers.facebook`. Is there any specific option where I need to make this change?

Comment: The switch is right on top of the app dashboard, next to the app id.